# ontimeupdate for HTML5 audio not firing in chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

I have the following code that creates an html5 audio element and sets a listener for when its time updates. The audio plays fine in all browsers except that the ontimeupdate function never fires in Chrome, including Chrome on Android.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
//
//set audio sources...
//
audioElement.ontimeupdate = function() {
  console.log('time update');
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work in Chrome? or perhaps an alternate event to use?

Answer (score 1):

I always use the [W3C Video test page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) to see when and if the event fire correctly.  And it is indicating that these events are fine on Android Chrome, Chrome Beta and an internal latest build I have.

Do you have any more information or a demo page to test from?

Comment: Video seems to be working (per the results) but audio not - at least of version 31.

Answer (score 1):

it's not proper to use

```
<script>
video.ontimeupdate=function(){

};
</script>
```

and i suggest you to use this code

```
<script>
video.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){

});
</script>
```

it will work properly on all supported html5 browsers

Comment: I disagree that it is improper to do it the first way, but regardless, I have tried it both ways and it doesn't work for me. Perhaps it is just the audio file I am trying to use.

Comment: Yes, Marty is absolutely correct. Chrome does not support ontimeupdate event. Both of the above CORRECT ways of doing it will fail in Chrome.

IE11 and Firefox work correctly, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a while ago, but I had this issue on a web jukebox project I was building...

```
var player = $("#player")[0];
player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    var songProgress = toHHMMSS( player.currentTime );
    $('#time-progress').text(songProgress);
});
```

...would never trigger whilst a file was playing (Chrome).  To get around this, I added...

```
 current-time="{{hostCurrentTime::timeupdate}}"
```

...to my audio element (so the HTML now reads)...

```
<audio id="player" src="" current-time="{{hostCurrentTime::timeupdate}}"></audio>
```

The timeupdate event is now triggered as expected.  I haven't used audio/video enough to know whether this is the right thing to do, so happy to be corrected.